# Word for someone who sleeps during the day

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

People are sometimes said to be a *morning person* or a *night person*. I also know that the term for something related to night is "nocturnal".

Is there a specific word for a person who sleeps during the day and is active at night? I’m looking for an elegant word for *night owl*.

Comment: I can think of _nighthawk_ and _nightbird_, but they aren't substantially different than _night owl_.

Comment: Vampire....? ;)

Comment: @Guffa +1 for vampire. I am a hopelessly nocturnal, and I often refer to myself as a vampire. But, yes, I use it facetiously.

Comment: There are two kinds of people in the world: *morning people* . . . and *slackers*.  Then there are cats, who seem to be both, but are actually *crepuscular*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question already contains the best adjective: ***[nocturnal](http://freedictionary.org/?Query=nocturnal)*** refers to being active at night and sleeping during the day. I don't know about elegant, but this is certainly the most technically-correct word you're going to find. Unfortunately, it doesn't have a noun form, but that can usually be fixed by rearranging your sentences a bit.

> Sally was a night owl who was always late to early-morning meetings. 
>   Sally's nocturnal tendencies made her chronically late to early-morning meetings.

I do want to note that in most contexts, I wouldn't interpret either *night owl* or *nocturnal* (when applied to people) as explicitly sleeping during the day and working at night. Both words just imply that, left to her own devices, Sally would prefer to go to bed late and get up late, where "late" could have different definitions for different people. If you need to make it clear that someone sleeps during the day, then either you need to say that ("sleeps during the day") or refer to them working the [***graveyard shift***](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/graveyard-shift.html) (which admittedly is not the most elegant of phrases).

Comment: I don't think I have my definitions backwards.

Comment: @Moshe Yes, you do.  Nocturnal animals are active at night and sleep during the day.  Diurnal animals are active during the day and sleep at night.  So, someone who is a night owl is a nocturnal person.  There are also crepuscular animals, which are active primarily at dawn and dusk, which are further broken down into matutinal, those active only at dawn, and vespertine, those active only at dusk.

Comment: @Moshe : you don't have your definitions backwards - I think Martha just read the question too quickly.

Comment: @cindi I know. :-)

Comment: I don't understand the upvotes. OP seems to be asking for a single-word **noun** to replace *night owl*. Defining the antonym of the **adjective** *nocturnal* doesn't really seem relevant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: you and Cindi are right, I misread the question. (Which doesn't invalidate my answer, just my phrasing of it.) Edited.

Comment: Okay - I've just reversed my downvote. I thought it was just me not being able to think of relevant terms for such a commonplace concept, but it's starting to look as if we simply don't have many. So +1 for "graveyard shift", which is at least in the right general area.

Comment: I also think "nocturnal" is good.  But technically it means he is awake during the night, and not necessarily that he sleeps during the day.

Comment: "Lark" and "owl" are commonly used among students and clinicians in sleep disorders; but as Martha points out, these denote variations within a fundamentally *diurnal* pattern.

Comment: There's nothing in the language to prohibit using 'nocturnal' as a noun: "Anne's a lark, up and about by five in the morning. Bob's an owl, hits his peak in the evening. But they're both diurnals; Charlie's a true nocturnal, works through the night and sleeps during the day."

Comment: @GEdgar [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocturnality)'Nocturnality is an animal behavior characterized by activity during the night and sleeping during the day. The common adjective is "nocturnal".'

Answer (score 3):

Carly Simon [sings](http://www.asklyrics.com/display/carly-simon-f-paul-and-linda-mccartney/night-owl-lyrics.htm), "I'm a *[night owl](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/night_owl)*, honey, sleep all day long."  Wiktionary defines *night owl* by "(idiomatic) One who stays up late at night or goes to bed late."

Answer (score 1):

It's [not unusual](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nocturnal%20person&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) to call someone a *night* or *nocturnal person* - normally it just means they "perk up" more in the evening, and don't tend to go to bed early. There's also [crepuscular](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/crepuscular) *(of twilight, dusk),* but that's not often applied to people. But as OP apparently knows, the standard term in common parlance is *night owl*.

It's not got quite the same meaning, but here in South-East England it's not unknown for parents to refer to their teenager as a [troglodyte](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/troglodyte) - meaning he spends all day in the darkened "cave" of his bedroom with the curtains drawn, only coming out to eat and socialise in the evening/night-time.

OP should definitely avoid referring to a female as a [lady of the night](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lady%20of%20the%20night), since that's generally understood to mean a prostitute.

Comment: Calling someone a *troglodyte* is only slightly better than calling them a four-letter word. I wouldn't suggest it anywhere near a context where elegance is required.

Comment: @Marthaª: *Early to bed, early to rise, makes a man healthy, wealthy, and wise.* Are there actually *any* contexts where we speaky positively of people who stay up late at night (and thus don't get up early in the morning)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of any. Our society has a definite prejudice against us nocturnal types.

Comment: Marthaª: My point exactly. But I hardly think saying my son is a *"troglodyte"* is on a par with saying he's a *"lazy c*nt"*, from his or other people's perspectives. Though I admit from *my* point of view they may both express much the same sentiment.

Answer (score 0):

A *late* riser may be described as someone who "sleeps in." Or you may use the term "late riser" itself.

Answer (score 0):

**[LychLobite](http://www.enacademic.com/searchall.php?SWord=lychnobite%20%20%20&from=en&to=&submitFormSearch=Search!&stype=0)**  One who turns night into day; a ‘fast liver’. Bailey vol. II, Lychnobite, a Night Walker …

Comment: A Russian-to-English translation dictionary of dubious quality makes a poor reference source. Also, you spelled it wrong. Also, you should include in your own words why you think this would be a good choice, including perhaps a sentence to demonstrate the usage.

Comment: @KitFox Clearly, the link shows that this reply was from Webster: 

2 Lychnobite ...One who labors at night and sleeps in the day. [1913 Webster] …

Answer (score 0):

The word *slugabed* describes someone who sleeps all day, but it's archaic. It also has a rather negative connotation, implying that the person sleeps because they are lazy, and not that they will get up and be productive at night.