# People who can't sleep at night

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Someone who sleeps during the day](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51197/someone-who-sleeps-during-the-day)

What is an appropriate word for people who can’t sleep at night but sleep peacefully in the daytime?

Comment: My first thought was "vampiric" - which means [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87525/what-does-vampiric-mean-in-this-context) might be possibly related. :^)

Comment: @StoneyB Why not vote to close as dupe then?

Comment: When it's pathological, it is called [narcolepsy or dyssomnia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcolepsy).

Comment: @Cerberus  *Narcolepsy*, however, is not a circadian sleep disorder.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇  I think it really wants to be merged, not closed.

Comment: @StoneyB First it gets closed as dupe, then merged later.

Comment: @StoneyB: So...? It fits the description, except that it is pathological.

Comment: @Cerberus  DSPD may be pathological, too, if it doesn't fit the sleeper's schedule. And narcolepsy is not what OP describes. Narcoleptics don't "sleep peacefully in the daytime" -- they have abrupt attacks of extreme sleepiness when waking. Likewise, they can sleep at night, but their sleep is  broken by abrupt awakenings.

Comment: @StoneyB: As I said, "when it's pathological". What the OP describes is not pathological. Narcolepsy is. Hence my qualification.

Comment: @Cerberus  And as I said, what OP describes, when pathological, is not narcolepsy but DSPD. Different symptoms, different etiology, different dx, different treatment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A difficulty or inability to sleep at night is known as **insomnia**, and one who suffers this condition is an **insomniac**. Sleeping during the day and remaining active at night is known as "nocturnality". Nocturnal only applies to creatures who only sleep during the day as their normal circadian sleep pattern, and therefore doesn't apply to humans (although it is sometimes used colloquially).

I think that what you're looking for is [delayed sleep phase disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_sleep_phase_disorder).